# Is there a way to combine 2 or more arrays while also combing duplicate data?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, concatenation

For some context I'm currently doing an assignment for college where i need to create a tournament scoring system, and this is my code so far.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace pointsSystemTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] e1Teams;
            int n = 4;
            int i;
            int pos1 = 20;
            int pos2 = 18;
            int pos3 = 15;
            int pos4 = 10;

            {
                {
                AssigningPointsE1:

                    e1Teams = new string[n];
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter the 4 teams in order of rank below");
                    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                    {
                        e1Teams[i] = Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                    if (e1Teams.Length != e1Teams.Distinct().Count())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("!CONTAINS DUPLICATES!");
                        Console.WriteLine("Please re-enter the teams for event 1 again");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        goto AssigningPointsE1;
                    }
                   

                    string e1p1 = e1Teams[0] + " - " + pos1 + "points";
                    string e1p2 = e1Teams[1] + " - " + pos2 + "points";
                    string e1p3 = e1Teams[2] + " - " + pos3 + "points";
                    string e1p4 = e1Teams[3] + " - " + pos4 + "points";

                    Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", e1p1);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", e1p2);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", e1p3);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", e1p4);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                string[] e2Teams;
                {
                AssigningPointsE2:

                    e2Teams = new string[n];
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter the 4 teams in order of rank below");
                    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                    {
                        e2Teams[i] = Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                    if (e2Teams.Length != e2Teams.Distinct().Count())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("!CONTAINS DUPLICATES!");
                        Console.WriteLine("Please re-enter the teams for event 1 again");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        goto AssigningPointsE2;
                    }

                    string e2p1 = e2Teams[0] + " - " + pos1 + "points";
                    string e2p2 = e2Teams[1] + " - " + pos2 + "points";
                    string e2p3 = e2Teams[2] + " - " + pos3 + "points";
                    string e2p4 = e2Teams[3] + " - " + pos4 + "points";

                    Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", e2p1);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", e2p2);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", e2p3);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", e2p4);
                    Console.ReadLine();


                 }
               }
            }
        }
    }
```

I basically would like to combine the 2 arrays into one array but I would also like to display the points each team has acquired during the tournament, the teams aren't entered in the same order so I'm struggling to combine the arrays and combine the points in one go.

I envisioned the final combination of points to look like:
team 1 - 40 points,
team 4 - ... points,
team 3 - ... points,
team 2 - ... points

Comment: Trying to uunderstand what your are doing. Here is my guess, there are 2 events,  top four team get a fixed number of points. You then want to add the total points up for each team. Correct? Plus there can be different teams in each event

Comment: Are there any wierd rules like, I can only use arrays, I cant use lists or dictionaries etc

Comment: So there are 4 teams in each event, and each team gets entered in a different order so receive points, there are 5 events in total but I haven’t written all the code for that yet. 

Also there are no rules they just want to see what we can do basically @pm100

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do

```
        var events = new List<string[]>() { e1Teams, e2Teams };
        var scores = new Dictionary<String, int>();
        var pointsTable = new int[] { 20, 18, 15, 10 };
        foreach (var ev in events) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                var team = ev[i];
                if (scores.ContainsKey(team)) {
                    scores[team] += pointsTable[i];
                }
                else
                    scores[team] = pointsTable[i];
            }
        }
        foreach (var kv in scores) {
            Console.WriteLine($"{kv.Key} - {kv.Value}");
        }
```

Note you would be way better off with not having a separate array for each event, have a list of lists